# Elastic Net scikit-learn: same model and input data but different prediction values

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, interpretation, scikit-learn, elastic-net

I was training an Elastic Net using scikit-learn and I bumped into the following problem. I am getting different prediction values for the same input data and model. What is happening? Am I missing something?

Here you have a toy example:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import ElasticNet
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

X, y = make_regression(n_samples=10, n_features=2, random_state=0)
regr = ElasticNet(random_state=0, warm_start=False)
kf = KFold(n_splits=2)

X_test_list_1 = []
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
    X_test_list_1.append(X_test)
    regr.fit(X_train, y_train)
    predictions = regr.predict(X_test)
    print(predictions)

print()

X_test_list_2 = []
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
    X_test_list_2.append(X_test)
    predictions = regr.predict(X_test)
    print(predictions)
```

This is the output that I get:

```
[27.21548741 18.76489499 12.36695569 30.60180003  5.28170604]
[11.52406875 34.01142154 15.00923603 48.67874968 53.77982218]

[182.36433553 -34.47392894  54.00462806 126.91247653 -42.29546465]
[11.52406875 34.01142154 15.00923603 48.67874968 53.77982218]
```

As you can see, only the last row of the second prediction matches the expected result.

I have checked both test datasets, but they are identical.
[image]

Comment: your `regr` object is re-fitted on each iteration in the first loop, but the second loop uses the `regr` fitted in the last iteration of the first loop

Comment: @ArtemMavrin Thanks for your comment, but warm_start is set to False by default in ElasticNet.

Comment: I mean that your second loop uses the same model in both iterations, but the first loop uses a different model in each iteration

Comment: @ArtemMavrin Ok, I got it! Thanks :)